# Is there a responsive-way of implementing this design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'd like to know what the best method of implementing this design would be, which I imagine would be in a responsive-sort of way. Here's a mockup. Notice my pretty blue square.

[image: Desktop-version of site mockup]

Now, here's the "mobile" version. As the width is reduced to where the blue square can't fit (while maintaining its size), it should drop below the **three** other content blocks.

[image: Mobile-version of site mockup]

I think this would be totally straight-forward if the blue block were to drop below the block immediately on its left, but that's not what the client wants. How would you accomplish this?

Comment: Flexbox, media queries, different ordering rules for different media sizes.

Comment: could you provide the basic markup of your blocks? are they all <div>s?

Comment: have you tried some of the answers below?

Answer (score 3):

for the blue block you could use a combination of `float: right` on high-res screen and `display: table-footer-group` on low-res screen so you don't need to move the blue block or use an hidden clone.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kwdrdy

---

Basic Markup

```
<main>

  <aside><div>1</div></aside>
  <section>2</section>
  <section>3</section>
  <section>4</section>

</main>
```

Css

```
section, aside { 
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px #ccc solid 
}

main {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

aside {
  display: table-footer-group;
}

aside div { background: #c2c1dc; width: 30%; margin: 0 auto;  }


@media all and (min-width: 600px) {

   main { display: block; }

   aside { float: right; width: 30%; margin: 0; }
   aside div { width: 100%; }
   aside + section { width: 68%; }

}
```

---

Screenshot on viewport < 600px

[image]

Screenshot on viewport > 600px

[image]

---

Note : `display: table-*` is well supported on all browsers, IE8+ included

Comment: Very nice - and mobile first for a leaner load.  Nice!

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a decent starting point,, utilising `order` to set the order elements display:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9381/)

HTML:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

CSS

```
 div {
    background:lightblue;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
    width:calc(100% - 130px);
}
div:nth-child(1) {
    background:lightgrey;
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        display:flex;
        flex-flow: column;
        text-align:center;
    }
    div, div:nth-of-type(1) {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    div:nth-of-type(1) {
        order:4;
        float:none;
    }
    div:nth-of-type(2) {
        order:1;
    }
    div:nth-of-type(3) {
        order:2;
    }
    div:nth-of-type(4) {
        order:3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about old position switch you can see in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpg80pwu/) - going from absolute to relative using media query?

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="block block1">1</div>
    <div class="block">2</div>
    <div class="block">3</div>
    <div class="block block3">4</div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    position: relative;
}
.block {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.block1 {
    width: 75%;
}
.block3 {
    width: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
@media all and (max-width: 350px) {
    .block1 {
        width: auto;
    }
    .block3 {
        width: auto;
        position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [flexbox layout mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes#Flexible_boxes_concept)

(*using the html elements from @fabrizio*)

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
aside {
  width: 100px;
  order: 4;
  background: lightblue
}
section {
  width: 100%;
}
section:first-child {
  flex: 1 0px
}
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  aside {
    order: 0
  }
}

/*next rule is for demo only*/
main > * {
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>content of section 1</section>
  <aside>content of aside 2</aside>
  <section>content of section 3</section>
  <section>content of section 4</section>
</main>
```

Demo also at http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/ZYbmYo

Comment: I like how succinct this is.